# Google places api issue in android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using google places api from an android device. Following is the snippet which I use, as explained in [this](http://www.claytical.com/blog/android-dynamic-autocompletion-using-google-places-api) tutorial.

```
            URL googlePlaces = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" +
            URLEncoder.encode(params[0], "UTF-8") +
                    "&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=" +
            getResources().getString(R.string.googleAPIKey));
            URLConnection tc = googlePlaces.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            tc.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            //take Google's legible JSON and turn it into one big string.
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                //turn that string into a JSON object
                Log.d("json predictions", "before predictions");
                JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                Log.d("json predictions", predictions.toString());
```

Exception as shown

```
02-07 17:25:38.830: D/dalvikvm(8984): Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-07 17:25:38.971: D/libEGL(8984): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:25:38.971: D/libEGL(8984): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:25:38.979: D/libEGL(8984): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
02-07 17:25:39.049: D/OpenGLRenderer(8984): Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 17:25:50.041: D/gottaGo3(8984): onTextChanged
02-07 17:25:50.041: D/gottaGo(8984): doInBackground
02-07 17:25:50.486: D/dalvikvm(8984): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 221K, 3% free 9155K/9412K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
02-07 17:25:50.518: D/gottaGo3(8984): onTextChanged
02-07 17:25:50.869: D/json predictions(8984): before predictions
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984): GetPlaces : doInBackground
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of {
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:362)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-07 17:25:50.869: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-07 17:25:50.869: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : 0
02-07 17:25:50.869: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter0
02-07 17:25:50.877: D/gottaGo(8984): doInBackground
02-07 17:25:51.275: D/gottaGo3(8984): onTextChanged
02-07 17:25:51.377: D/json predictions(8984): before predictions
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984): GetPlaces : doInBackground
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of {
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:362)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-07 17:25:51.385: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-07 17:25:51.385: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : 0
02-07 17:25:51.385: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter0
02-07 17:25:51.393: D/gottaGo(8984): doInBackground
02-07 17:25:51.893: D/json predictions(8984): before predictions
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984): GetPlaces : doInBackground
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of {
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:362)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-07 17:25:51.893: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-07 17:25:51.893: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : 0
02-07 17:25:51.893: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter0
02-07 17:25:56.627: D/gottaGo3(8984): onTextChanged
02-07 17:25:56.627: D/gottaGo(8984): doInBackground
02-07 17:25:57.135: D/json predictions(8984): before predictions
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984): GetPlaces : doInBackground
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 1 of {
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:362)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
 02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):   at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at com.test.locationautocomplete.MainActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-07 17:25:57.135: E/YourApp(8984):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-07 17:25:57.143: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : 0
02-07 17:25:57.143: D/YourApp(8984): onPostExecute : autoCompleteAdapter0
```

What is the reason for this error, though it works from browser?

Comment: could you post the full link with its parameters ?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=delhi&types=geocode&language=en&sensor=true&key=myapikey - myapikey is something which I obtained from google console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close while loop brackets before this Line
JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

```
 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
 }
 //turn that string into a JSON object

 Log.d("json predictions", "before predictions");
 JSONObject predictions = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
 Log.d("json predictions", predictions.toString());
```